# Pushbullet notification on arch linux - Failed to decode JSON body

Tags: json, pushbullet

I am trying to get a script working from here :
https://gist.github.com/vor0nwe/e33ace72c850f93bc979/

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -u YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN: \
-X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"type":"note","title":"Downloaded","body":"$TR_TORRENT_NAME: $TR_TIME_LOCALTIME"}'
```

on my zyxel325 nas but every time I get this message :

```
{"error":{"type":"invalid_request","message":"Failed to decode JSON body.","cat":"(=^‥^=)"}}
```

I tried putting the "`$TR_TORRENT_NAME: $TR_TIME_LOCALTIME`" in double "" but it did not help.

If someone could help I would be grateful.
Cheers

Comment: Does it work if you don't use "$TR_TORRENT_NAME: $TR_TIME_LOCALTIME" but just put "hello" there instead?

Comment: Then it works but I tried it from cmd line. What does it mean?

Comment: But the script is not being executed by transmission.

Comment: I have an update. After deleting the back slash from the end of Content-Type: application/json' \  the whole script works. Now it the problem is that the Transmission is not executing it despite the fact that in the log it "calls the script".

Comment: Ok I managed to resolve the problem. There were probably 2 issues: 1) instead of bin/bash command I had to change to bin/sh 2)changed the file formating from dos to unix (ASCII)